# Jquery this selector by using string

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there any equivalent to $(this) by using a string expression? I have tried $('this') but I could not be successful.

Edit:

I would like to reduce the amount of the code for my dom elements. Instead of repeating my codes, I would like to write a custom attribute and putting response to data-response-target-sel selector. However sometimes I need to basically express this selector by using context of "this". I would like to find a good solution for such cases. I can add another custom attribute for context but before going further more I wanted to share my question.

`<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"  data-response-target-sel=".modal" >`

```
ajaxSubmit({
    url: $this.attr("href"),
    type: "GET",
    data: {}
},$this.attr("data-response-target-sel"));


function ajaxSubmit(data,resSel) {
  $.ajax({
     url:data.url,
     type:data.type,
     data:data.data,
     cache:false,
     success:function (html, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var $html = $(html);
        if(jqXHR.status == 200 || jqXHR.status == 201){
            $(resSel).html(html)
        }
     }
  });
```

}

How can I set "data-response-target-sel" for context using this?

Thanks

Comment: Tell us what you're trying to do, and post some code....

Comment: That's because `$('this')` will try to select any HTML elements called `this`, of which I'm assuming there are none.  Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Please add some information to your question. What are you trying to archive? What have you done so far?

Comment: Huh? `$(this)` wraps the current object into a jQuery object. Why do you need to use a string if `$(this)` works? Anyway, you'd have to check if the `this` object has id - if yes, use that, if not, you'd have to find it in the DOM tree and reference it somehow according to its position...

Comment: @David. not called, their tag name is `this`

Comment: @gdoron: I guess "called" is ambiguous in my context, but that's what I meant :)

Comment: @Cemo. I'm afraid it's still not clear what are you trying to do. maybe a code snippet?

Comment: @David. Added a note about `$('this')` in my answer. take a look

Comment: Hey guys who voted downs, expecting an answer from yours.

Comment: People downvote because you didn't put any effort into asking your question. Don't expect people to put effort into answering when you don't bother putting effort into your question. I see you've edited in information now - Why wasn't that your original question?

Comment: Take a look on my updated answer.

Comment: Because I did not want to bother you by asking a complicated question. It does not mean I did not respect you or something else. Now you saw the motivation behind my question but I still believe that it does not make a lot of sense for you. And more and more I start to see more and more degeneration of the Stackoverflow Community. Anyway thanks for your response.

Comment: @Cemo I didn't mean any offense, simply trying to help you. Low quality questions generally get low quality answers. Garbage in Garbage Out.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any equivalent to $(this) by using a string expression?

No, unless you use something like the evil `eval`.

Why do you need a string equivalent to `this`?
If I can find something like: `$('kdjfk55ndns')` would you use it?

Read   https://stackoverflow.com/q/10375329/601179 if you really want answers like the above...

---

Note that `$('this')` query the DOM looking for elements with `this` **tagName**:

```
<this>
    <this> </this>
</this>
```

There are many of those in HTML...

---

**Update:**

```
function ajaxSubmit(data,resSel) {
  $.ajax({
     url:data.url,
     type:data.type,
     data:data.data,
     cache:false,
     context : $(resSel),
     success:function (html, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var $html = $(html);
        if(jqXHR.status == 200 || jqXHR.status == 201){
            this.html(html)
        }
     }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try defining `$(this)` as a variable and use then use that.

```
var obj = $(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd pass your element along, you could do this:

```
$('selector', $this);
```

or in your example:

```
$(resSel, $this).html(html)
```

and don't use

```
$this.attr("data-response-target-sel")
```

but

```
$this.data("response-target-sel")
```

Comment: But I would like to use "this context" optional. How would I express it elegantly by using strings. I hope that you understood my concern. By the way thanks for the "data" tip.